# How to trigger <tab> auto completion in a key mapping?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion

I'd like to map <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> in normal mode to showing the auto completions of files to edit.

I tried `nnoremap <leader>e :e<space><tab>`, but it shows `:e ^I`, where the tab gets rendered as `^I` rather than triggering the auto completions.

Using `nnoremap <leader>e :e<space>` correctly prints `:e` but I obviously have to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> manually in this case.

How can trigger the auto completions to show up in a key binding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `:nnoremap <leader>e :call feedkeys(':e<space><tab>','t')<cr>`

the `t` indicates to use the keys as typed (as opposed to coming from a mapping)

Answer (score 3):

You could also give the same value to the `'wildchar'` and `'wildcharm'` options:

```
set wc=9
set wcm=9
```

`9` is the decimal code of the `Tab` key.

---

For your particular issue, `'wcm'` is probably the only option you need to set.

It determines which key must be pressed during the recording of a macro, or in the `{rhs}` of a mapping to start wildcard expansion in the command-line.

However, you should probably give it the same value as `'wc'`, otherwise you won't be able to replay a macro opening the wildmenu:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted, but I'm a bit confused by your mention of recording macros. As far as I can tell from the documentation (and experimentation) the `wildcharm` setting doesn't affect recorded macros? (The documentation for it does mention the word "macro", but like the rest of the documentation it uses that term to refer to *mappings*.)

Comment: @Rich On my machine, if `'wcm'` is not configured like `'wc'`, the replay of a macro which opens the wildmenu doesn't work. I included a gif to show it. In it, I first give to `'wc'` the value `9` (`Tab` key) and to `'wcm'` the value `94` (`C-z` suggested in `:h 'wcm`). The replay of the macro (`@q`) fails to edit `file2` like what was done during the recording. When I give to both options the same value, `@q` works as expected.

Comment: @Rich Sorry I was wrong, `94` is not the decimal code of `C-z`. I should have used `26`. But it doesn't change the result of the experiment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I made a mistake when I was testing it: my completion (after a single `Tab`) was a directory. So I got an "Illegal file name" error. Then when I played back the macro I got the same "Illegal file name" error. I interpreted this as the file name having been completed, but actually it was performing a bare `:e` and using the file name of the buffer (which had been set when recording the macro). Duh.