# `q` does not record tab completion correctly

Tags: autocompletion, macro

Whenever I want to record complex macro between <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>q</kbd>, I have to remember that, for instance, I can't use <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion while type some `ex` command, otherwise the macro will not work.

Have I really to teach myself avoiding <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion (which is so aggressive in my muscle memory) while recording a macro? Or is there a way to make it work?

(BTW, <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion is not even available when I enter Vim by `vi -u NONE` (but it is if I simply delete my `.vimrc` file), so maybe the problem is an obvious consequence of how the `<Tab>` mapping works.)

Comment: Try `set wc=9 wcm=9`. See `:h 'wcm`.

Comment: @user938271, your comment **is** the answer indeed! Can you please explain why the _9_? I can't find an answer in the `:help wcm`.

Comment: `9` is the decimal code of the `Tab` character in the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart). `set wc=9` is equivalent to `set wc=<Tab>` and tells Vim that a Tab character should start a wildcard expansion. `set wcm=9` is equivalent to `set wcm=<Tab>` and tells Vim that a Tab character should start a wildcard expansion, but inside a mapping or a macro. You can give whatever value you want to both options, however [they must be identical](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15122/17449).

Comment: Otherwise, the replay of a macro which starts a wildcard expansion will fail. And since you probably want to use the Tab key, `set wc=9 wcm=9` seems to be what you (anyone?) would want.

Comment: @user938271, it seems that `wcm=9` is enough, just like `wc` and `wcm` are not orthogonal and that `wcm` does something more and nothing less than `wc`. Can you confirm this? And maybe put it in an answer that I can accept.

Comment: I think that `set wcm=9` is enough because `<Tab>` is the default value of `'wc'`, and because even if you change its value, the Tab key still starts a wildcard expansion (it may be hard-coded in Vim).  Try this: `set wc=26 wcm=9` (26 is the decimal code of `C-z`), then record your macro by pressing `C-z` instead of `Tab`. The replay will fail. Now try this: `set wc=26 wcm=26`, then record your macro by pressing again `C-z` instead of `Tab`. This time, the replay will work.

Comment: I don't want to remember this, so I set them both with the same value. This way, when I re-read my vimrc, I have less questions in my mind. I don't want to write an answer because of what the help says at `:h c_wildchar`: `Note: does not work inside a macro, because <Tab> or <Esc> are mostly used as 'wildchar', and these have a special meaning in some macros.` I'm not sure there won't be an issue later. Personally, I never had one, but I don't use macros that much. Use it for some time, and if you never encounter any issue, write an answer. It's fine to answer your own question.

Comment: I have found a real example where `set wcm=9` causes an issue. See `:h hitest.vim`. It talks about a script which can give you information about your highlight groups. To use it, you're supposed to execute `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim`. But it won't work properly if you have `set wcm=9` in your vimrc. There'll be an error message (`E475`), and the text written by the script in a new buffer won't be highlighted, while it should.

Comment: This is because the script copies Ex commands from the buffer to a register, then run the register as a macro. The lines contain Tab characters. Because of `set wcm=9`, Vim interprets them as wildcard expansions, while it should just insert them on the command-line. It may be why the help at `:h 'wcm` suggests using `C-z` instead of Tab. To avoid this kind of issue, you would have to use `set wcm=26`, and press `C-z` instead of Tab while recording your macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no actual questions in your submission but one can be inferred: Why doesn't Tab do wildcard expansion with `-u NONE`?

`-u NONE` prevents any vimrc files from being loaded. That results in default values being used for settings and that includes the Vi compatibility setting `'compatible'`. This will be enabled per `:h 'compatible'`. Further, the wildcard expansion key is specified in `'wildchar'`. The Vim default is, of course, `<Tab>` but, per `:h 'wc'`, the Vi default (applicable because of `'compatible'`) is `CTRL-E`. Enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> instead of <kbd>TAB</kbd> and expansion should work in that scenario.

BTW, wildcard expansion is really an interactive feature while  macros are non-interactive. Except for muscle-memory mistakes there shouldn't be any reason command-line Tabs get entered in your macros.

**Update:** Addressing questions added after I wrote the preceding...between something that will help you avoid typing <kbd>TAB</kbd> or something that will make expansion work the latter is the most realistic (though ill-advised, IMO, except for some specific use cases). In fact, @user938271 gave you [a hint about this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18124/q-does-not-record-tab-completion-correctly/18131#).

I talked about `'wildchar'` above. Expansion can't reliably be done in deferred/non-interactive contexts (i.e. a macro/mapping) using this mechanism but there is a related setting `'wildcharm'` that provides a means to do so as indicated in the associated help:

> 'wildcharm' works exactly like 'wildchar', except that it is
>     recognized when used inside a macro <sup>1</sup>. ... Normally  you'll never actually type 'wildcharm',
>   just use it in mappings [and macros].

`wildcharm`/`wcm` is not set by default so we need to do `:set wcm=XXX` replacing `XXX` with whatever unused key you prefer, e.g. `:set wcm=<Tab>`. (Note: `'wcm'` is supposed to be set to a number but the `<FOO>` notation is a legal substitute.) Your issue with macros should be taken care of now.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note that Vim documentation has a broader definition of "macro" than some are accustomed to. The term is popularly used most commonly to refer to commands recorded into a register and played back with `@`. Vim help files, though, sometimes refer to the RHS of key mappings as macros, too.</sub>

Comment: I'm sorry for having used no _?_ in the question. Anyway my true question more like _How can I have Tab work in recorded command-line macros?_

Comment: @Enrico I answered that question. Look at the last line. The only thing I didn't do is show the exact command for Tab (the example is for Ctrl-Z which is the default.). All you need to do is replace `<C-Z>` with `<Tab>`: `:set wcm=<Tab>`.

Comment: There. Now it shows the command for Tab, too.

Comment: The last two lines of your answer actually answer the question, so I'll accept it. The excerpt you quoted seems useful as well, I'll try to understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks, @Enrico. In retrospect what I excerpted is a bit confusing. The important part is the first sentence. The rest is about mappings not macros so off topic for you question.  (Side note: I think the first sentence should say "...inside a macro or mapping").  I'll try to clean it up a bit when I get a chance but it boils down to this: expansion can't reliably be done in deferred/non-interactive contexts (i.e. a macro or mapping) using the normal mechanism but `'wcm'` provides a means to do so.